# autocomplete fragment is not working properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have used the below code to search for places in my application.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()).title(String.valueOf(place.getName())));
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 12.0f));

            }
```

But whenever I click the search box, it appears for a second and then disappears.

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue when developing with Google Maps Platform.

Please follow these steps:

1- Login to Google Cloud Console.

2- Select or Create your associated project with API KEY.

3- Enable Places API in Console

To get a API key check [Setup API KEY](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup)

Comment: Brother, I used both the `places autocomplete fragment and place autocomplete activity`, the activity is working properly but not the fragment, appear and disappeared...

Comment: Yup, I was missing **enabling** `Places SDK for Android`. Thank you, Zaid.

Comment: @yahme3 is Autocomplete search for place is working now?